# error no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: r

Here is my script (I try to: read csv -- rename all columns name -- select some of the columns and write the output as another csv)

but I get error for select function:

> Error in `UseMethod("select_")` :
>   no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class
>   "character"

Here is my code:

```
 Old_Data <-
 read.csv("K:/International/New Miestone.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(Old_Data) <-
    c("Enrol.Year",
    "VTAC.Course.Code",and so on)%>%

select(
"Enrol.Year", and so on)

write.csv(Old_data,path,.....)
```

Strangely, I used to import data from txt file and set names for headers, then select, then write csv, never has such problem

Comment: sorry not sure if I understand correct or not. 1) names(Old_Data) <- c("Enrol.Year", "VTAC.Course.Code",and so on)   2)Old_data%>%  3)select( "Enrol.Year", and so on)?  but still doesn't work

Comment: added an answer see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

#Read the csv
Old_Data <- read.csv("K:/International/New Miestone.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#Rename all the columns and select required columns
New_Data <- Old_Data %>%
             rename_all(funs(c("Enrol.Year", "VTAC.Course.Code",...))) %>%
             select(Enrol.Year,  VTAC.Course.Code, ...)

#Write the csv
write.csv(New_Data,path)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works -- however, could you let me know what's the difference bewtween your code and mine? don't understand why mine doens't work

Comment: @Baron you are doing `names(OldData)  <-` and trying to change the names and then you continue with pipe operation,  so instead of having a dataframe object you are trying to work only with names of the dataframe.